# How can I replace Ant with Maven?

Tags: maven-2, ant

What are the minimum steps I should follow to replace Ant with Maven?

Answer (score 13):

1. Set up your project according to the [standard directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).
2. Create a [minimal pom.xml](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Minimal_POM) with groupId, artifactId and version.
3. Add your [dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) to the pom.xml
4. Compare the WAR/JAR/EAR to the old version see if there is any change. Take actions to minimize the differences as told [here](http://blog.manupk.com/2014/02/4-simple-steps-to-migrate-legacy.html).

You should now be able to build a simple project, run the tests and package it.

Answer (score 8):

Anecdote: Once you are in Maven, the reverse trip (though why would you ever go back!) is so simple:

```
mvn ant:ant
```

[generates functionally equivalent ant scripts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ant-plugin/).  Now if only an Ant->Maven generator existed.

Comment: the only source for mvn->ant migration I was able to find within 10 minutes. Thanks, Matthew

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to [ant2maven](https://github.com/ewhauser/ant2maven) script, that builds pom.xml from Ant scripts. I've never tried it, but it can be used to have a good pom.xml to start with...